# Convert Excel to XML format for each row in excel

Tags: excel, xml

Source of Excel:

```
+---------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------+
| Subject |  Mode   | Name  | ClassNo  | Student | Seat |
+---------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------+
| English | Online  | Mr. A | AAAAAAAA |      15 |      |
| Chinese | Offline | Alex  | B        |      30 |   80 |
+---------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------+
```

Desire Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<FileLoad>
  <Subject>English</XML_LOADPGM>
  <Mode>Online</XML_MODE>
  <Application>
    <Name>Mr. A</Name>
    <ClassNo>AAAAAAAA</ClassNo>
    <Student>15</Student>
    <Seat/>
  </Application>
</FileLoad>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<FileLoad>
  <Subject>Chinese</XML_LOADPGM>
  <Mode>Offline</XML_MODE>
  <Application>
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <ClassNo>B</ClassNo>
    <Student>30</Student>
    <Seat>80</Seat>
  </Application>
</FileLoad>
```

I have tried to use Convert Excel to XML method, but I can't get the desire output as I want. Is there any other workaround solution convert from excel to desired output XML? I want exactly same as desired output.

Tried using convert excel to XML format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FileLoad xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Subject>English</XML_LOADPGM>
  <Mode>Online</XML_MODE>
  <Application>
    <Name>Mr. A</Name>
    <ClassNo>AAAAAAAA</ClassNo>
    <Student>15</Student>
  </Application>
</FileLoad>
```

1. 1st line - Get double quote instead of single code
2. 1st line - Get standalone wording
3. 2nd line - Get the link
4. 9th line - I want those empty value for seat, to be in tag as

Comment: If you save your Excel as a CSV first, you will find there are numerous website that can be used to convert that into XML or JSON. I am sure one of them would give you what you are after. For example... https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-xml.htm

Comment: @JGFMK tqvm! This is what i want. I have successfully customize the result i want